# Как обработать и получить данные из xml строки?

Tags: php, xml

Через сервис переводов bing через api получаю ответ в виде:

```
<GetTranslationsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <From>en</From>
    <Translations>
        <TranslationMatch>
            <Count>0</Count>
            <MatchDegree>100</MatchDegree>
            <MatchedOriginalText/>
            <Rating>5</Rating>
            <TranslatedText>Позволяет поддоменов для перенаправления URI, указанный при вызове потока согласия. В большинстве сценариев это должно оставаться снят.</TranslatedText>
        </TranslationMatch>
    </Translations>
</GetTranslationsResponse>
```

Пытаюсь обработать данные функцией simplexml_load_string, но получаю пустую строку.
Как получить узел TranslatedText?

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = '<GetTranslationsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><From>en</From><Translations><TranslationMatch><Count>0</Count><MatchDegree>100</MatchDegree><MatchedOriginalText/><Rating>5</Rating><TranslatedText>Позволяет поддоменов для перенаправления URI, указанный при вызове потока согласия. В большинстве сценариев это должно оставаться снят.</TranslatedText></TranslationMatch></Translations></GetTranslationsResponse>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
var_dump($xml);
```

Вот что я получил из вашего кода. Ничего не меняя:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["From"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["Translations"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["TranslationMatch"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (5) {
      ["Count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["MatchDegree"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["MatchedOriginalText"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {
      }
      ["Rating"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["TranslatedText"]=>
      string(248) "Позволяет поддоменов для перенаправления URI, указанный при вызове потока согласия. В большинстве сценариев это должно оставаться снят."
    }
  }
}
```